# grep error when search for pairs of numeric digits

Tags: linux, bash, grep, centos

This is only a portion of a shell script.

I am trying to list(sort by date) folders that are matched by pairs of numeric digits using grep.

The first command works but the second command fails. Can't figure out exactly why it fails.

```
[root@server backup]# ls -lt | grep 202[0-1]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9]
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Dec  8 08:44 2020-12-08
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Dec  6 08:45 2020-12-06
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Nov 20 02:00 2020-11-20
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Nov 10 02:00 2020-11-10
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 30 02:00 2020-10-30
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 27 02:00 2020-10-27
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 25 02:00 2020-10-25
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 23 10:40 2020-10-23
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 20 02:00 2020-10-20
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 18 02:00 2020-10-18
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 16 11:10 2020-10-16
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 13 02:00 2020-10-13
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct 11 02:00 2020-10-11
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct  9 02:00 2020-10-09
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct  6 10:16 2020-10-06
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct  4 02:00 2020-10-04
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Oct  2 02:00 2020-10-02
drwx--x--x 4 root root  4096 Sep 20 02:00 2020-09-20
```

But with this one, it shows the error **Is a directory**

```
[root@server backup]# ls -lt | grep 202[0-1]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
grep: 2020-10-02: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-04: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-06: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-09: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-11: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-13: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-16: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-18: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-20: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-23: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-25: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-27: Is a directory
grep: 2020-10-30: Is a directory
grep: 2020-11-10: Is a directory
grep: 2020-11-20: Is a directory
grep: 2020-12-06: Is a directory
grep: 2020-12-08: Is a directory
```

What's wrong am I doing with grep in the second command from the output of **ls -lt** ?.

Comment: `ls -lt 202[0-1]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]`? [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Add quotes: `ls -lt | grep '202[0-1]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9]'`

Comment: That worked :) excellent. What's the difference quote makes there? Without quotes, grep think it is going recursive?

Comment: for the 2nd (failed) command, what is the output from `ls -lt`?

Comment: Without the quotes, the shell expands that pattern into a bunch of filenames that are `grep`'s command line arguments and it tries to use the first as a RE and the rest as files to scan. See my first comment; there's no reason for `grep` to be used here at all.

Comment: Shawn, yes, simply ls -ltd 202[0-1]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] works not ls -l(which list all sub directories of those folders as well), but thank you so much :)